# What is class better for use between XSSFWorksheet and SXSSFWorksheet ?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on j2ee project with struts2 framework and i need to read and write large excel file approximate 150 mb. so what class should i use for this task between XSSFWorksheet and SXSSFWorksheet class.

I don't know that what class is maximum capable aspect of speed and large processing.

what are difference between in both ?

please suggest me.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For a comparison of XSSF and SXSSF, look no further than the [Apache POI Spreadsheets page](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/). That lists what the two APIs can and can't do, compares them etc. Must of you question can be solved just by looking at it

Taking this one bit of your question:

> i need to read and write large excel file

XSSF supports both reading and writing. SXSSF only supports appending data when writing, it does not support reading

So, you'll need to use XSSF to read your files (or the very low level [SAX stuff](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)). For writing, you might be able to use SXSSF, assuming you're only ever appending new data, otherwise XSSF will be your only option again